# Update_post_meta or update_meta_data for Woocommerce orders not works for me

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i'm trying to modify or add (this last is an option when update works) attributes into a product order on Woocommerce.

This is into a shortcode function and i just show you relevant part of the code. I get data form url args and data is ok because i had print before update_meta_data and it's all ok.

```
   $pOrderId = null;
   $pText = '';
   $pDisseny = '';
   $pState = null;
   $pOrder = null;
   $codeResult = '';
   
   $pOrderId = sanitize_text_field($_GET['orderId']);
   $pText = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ptext']);
   $pDisseny = sanitize_text_field($_POST['selDisseny']);
   $pState = is_null($_POST['saveState'])?0:intval($_POST['saveState']);
   
   if ($pOrderId != null){

        $pOrder = wc_get_order($pOrderId);  
        
        if ($pState == 1){
            $pOrder->update_meta_data('pa_disseny', $pDisseny );
        }
        
        $pOrderItems = $pOrder->get_items();
```

This is the WC_Meta_Data object to update from product order

```
[2] = > OBJECT (WC_Meta_Data) #29867(2) { ["current_data":protected] = > array(3) { ["id"] = > INT (202) ["key"] = > string(10) "pa_disseny" ["value"] = > string(9) "disseny-1" } ["data":protected] = > array(3) { ["id"] = > INT (202) ["key"] = > string(10) "pa_disseny" ["value"] = > string(9) "disseny-1" } }
```

I don't see the problem. I have search from some solution but i don't find it because when i have find some similar their solution is'n work for me.

I need some help.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I was trying to update meta of the order, but the order is composed bu products. I only needed to update product object into the order, and now works.

```
$pOrderId = null;
$pDisseny = '';
$pOrder = null;
   
   $pOrderId = sanitize_text_field($_GET['orderId']);
   $pDisseny = sanitize_text_field($_POST['selDisseny']);
   
   if ($pOrderId != null){

        $pOrder = wc_get_order($pOrderId);        
        $pOrderItems = $pOrder->get_items();

        foreach( $pOrderItems as $product ) {       

                $product->update_meta_data('pa_disseny', $pDisseny );
                $product->save();
        }
}
```